# rectify image in your package

Tags: ros, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I have a package which has 2 image_info and camera topics:

nh_.param("input_image_topic", input_image_topic_, std::string("/camera"));
nh_.param("input_camera_info_topic", input_camera_info_topic_, std::string("/camera_info"));

I am wondering if there is a way to rectify images in my package.

I donot want to use the image_proc in a launch file. I need the rectify images to be called in my package to do some processing.

cheers,
Eddi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29540/rectify-image-in-your-package/) by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2012-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The whole architecture of ROS makes the assumption that one wants to distribute the computation on several nodes dedicated to a particular subproblem that needs to be solved. Therefore, there is no direct API in image_proc to rectify an image. If performance is a problem, you may run both your algorithm and the rectification in the same process using nodelets.

Doing things differently and trying to extract C++ API from ROS nodes is not a good idea. If you really want to do so, then ROS is probably not the right tool for you and you should directly use OpenCV API.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply subscribe to the rectified topic and do the processing with your node.
However if you are interested in removing that small overhead of communication you can still make a copy of the image_proc node, rename, and modify it to fit your needs.

You can fetch the code from the subversion repo: http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1